# Java android delete File

Tags: java

I want to delete a file (pdf file) I did this :

```
boolean deleted = filesList.get(pos).delete();
```

But when I look in my phone I see this file , but my application doesn't see this file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete a file from a directory, you can use this method:

```
public static void deleteFile(File directory, String fileName) {

    if (directory.isDirectory()) {
        for(File file : directory.listFiles()) {

            if (file.getName().contains(fileName)) {

                if (file.isFile()) {
                    if (file.exists()) {
                        file.delete();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And if you want to delete the entire directory:

```
public static void deleteDirectory(File directory) {
    if (directory.isDirectory())
        for (File child : directory.listFiles())
            deleteDirectory(child);

    directory.delete();
}
```

As mentioned by `ylmzekrm1223`, you should provide permissions to read and write storage in your *AndroidManifest.xml*, before attempting to delete a file or a directory.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't delete a file from the file system. It just deletes an element from the list.
Check this for more 
[delete file in sdcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248292/how-to-delete-a-file-from-sd-card)

To delete a file from the file system, first you need to provide Permission to read and write local storage in your *AndroidManifest.xml*

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE">     
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Then, in your code,

```
String path =  "/mnt/sdcard/test.pdf";
File mFile = new File(path);
mFile.delete();
```